# Dynamically configure the Number Formatting in Angular based on Culture Info

Tags: angular, number-formatting, cultureinfo

I have a API that returns the required formats for my Angular application.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": null,
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "countryCode": "USA",
    "dateTimeFormat": {
      "date": "dd-MM-yyyy",
      "time": "hh:mm:ss tt"
    },
    "currencyFormat": {
      "grouping": ",",
      "decimal": ".",
      "currency": "USD",
      "pattern": "$",
      "culture": "en-US",
      "formatSpecifier": "c",
      "decimalDigits": 2
    },
    "numberFormat": {
      "culture": "en-US",
      "formatSpecifier": "n",
      "decimalDigits": 2
    },
    "percentFormat": {
      "culture": "en-US",
      "formatSpecifier": "p",
      "decimalDigits": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I need to use this info (e.g. **numberFormat** object from the response) and format all the numbers displayed in the entire angular application. Is there any way to do this in Angular?

Comment: i think you should use custom pipe

Comment: @ArashHatami Any relevant references?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Pipes takes the integers, strings, arrays, and dates as input separated with | to be converted in the format as required and display same in a browser. Inside the interpolation expression, we can define the pipe and use it based on the situation as there are many types of pipes we can use in an Angular application.
You should use pipe with multiple args provided with numberFormat.

You can pass a parameter to your pipe like this:

```
{{ whatever | mypipe: 'option1' }}
```

This will be passed into your pipe.ts as args:

```
transform(value: any, args?: string) {
  switch (args) {
    case 'option1':
      return handleOption1(value);
    case 'option2':
      return handleOption2(value);
    ...
  }
}
```

[this link can help you to write custome pipe.](https://medium.com/better-programming/creating-a-custom-pipe-for-your-angular-app-64b419a93f2a)